# get product code in featured products module opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I want to get product code (module) into featured products module opencart

see this example of what I want 
http://demo.pure-sol.com/fahmy/test.jpg

I did some code but there something wrong with the result

**\catalog\controller\module\featured.php**

```
$this->data['text_model'] = $this->language->get('text_model'); // line 10
$this->data['model'] = $product_info['model']; // line 54
```

**catalog\language\english\module\featured.php**

```
$_['text_model']        = 'Model';
```

**catalog\view\theme\fashionfever\template\module\featured.tpl**

```
<div class="feature">

  <h2> <?php echo $heading_title; ?></h2>
  <div class="box-content">
    <div class="box-product">
      <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
      <div>
        <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
        <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
        <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
        <div class="price">
          <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
          <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
        <div class="rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" /></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="cart"><input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" /></div>
      </div>
```

> ```
>  <!-- additional code -->
>            <p><?php echo $text_model; ?>: <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $model; ?></a></p>
> ```

```
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the line

`$this->data['model'] = $product_info['model']; // line 54`

and in `$this->data['products'][] = array(`

add this line

```
'model'       => $product_info['model'],
```

add this

```
<p><?php echo $text_model; ?>: <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['model']; ?></a></p>
```

just after

```
<div class="cart"><input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" /></div>
```